# How do I access a resource(style) through code?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Resource Dictionary containing all my custom styles for the programs controls.
The Dictionary is mergerd with the application's resources as displayed below:

```
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Controls">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

I can easily access the different styles through xaml:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Button}" />
```

But whenever I try assigning controls with this style through code, it fails.

I've tried:

```
    Button.Style = Application.Current.Resources("Button")

    Button.Style = CType(Application.Current.Resources("Button"), Style)
```

And different approaches similar to the ones above.
During testing some of the different ways to get the styles, I was faced with "Resource not found" but when using the above ones the program seemed to find the style.
I could successfully run the program - but without any visual proof that the style was indeed applied.

How do I properly assign a control a style found in a Resource Dictionary?

Comment: Try [Application.FindResource Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource.aspx).

Comment: Why would you want to do that in code, Alex? [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35346/Using-a-Resource-Dictionary-in-WPF), hope this helps, though i strongly disapprove...

Comment: @StefanDenchev I have to make a control dynamically.
I.e.
Dim newButton as new Button - and then style it accordingly.
Of course I could always make a new style through code, but I already have a perfect one in xaml resources.

Comment: Edit: After testing, this is exactly what I needed. Will add an Answer and close this thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*For any descendants: here is how I succeded to apply a style from a resource to a dynamically created control through code. (Given that you have a Resource Dictionary containing the style)*

**First step: Include the Resource Dictionary**

To make a Resource Dictionary easily accessible from code, add it through code.

VB

```
  Dim myResourceDictionary As New ResourceDictionary
  myResourceDictionary .Source = New _
  Uri("/YourApplication;component/YourDictionary.xaml",
        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

C#

```
   var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
       {
           Source = new Uri("/YourApplication;component/YourDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
       };
```

Replace "YourApplication" with your solution name, and "YourDictionary" with your Resource Dictionary file.

**Second step: Assign the Style**

To make use of the newly imported Resource Dictionary, simply assign a control a style;

VB

```
  Dim myButton As New Button
  Dim myButtonStyle As Style = myResourceDictionary("YourStyleKey")
  myButton.Style = myButtonStyle
```

C#

```
  var myButtonStyle= myResourceDictionary["YourStyleKey"] as Style;
  var myButton = new Button { Style = myButtonStyle };
```

*Special thanks to user [Stefan Denchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1638430/stefan-denchev) for giving me an [article covering this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35346/Using-a-Resource-Dictionary-in-WPF).
As C# isn't my strong side, please edit this if I've made any mistake.*

Comment: Fyi: you can use `var` in C# (i.e. `var myButton = new Button();`).

Comment: Oh, ok. But how would I set it to a type? Like myButton as Button?

Comment: Does this code look for a style in `myResourceDictionary`’s `MergedDictionaries`, too?

Answer (score 5):

Use Application.Current.Resources["Button"].

Comment: Unfortuneatly this didn't work, I will add an answer of what Stefan Denchev posted. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was using nested dictionaries, where accessing the resource directly by using `Application.Current.Resources[]` or `App.Current.FindResource()` didn't work.

I had to specify the specific dictionary to be able to access the resource:

```
((ResourceDictionary)Application.Current.Resources["ResourceDictionary"])["StaticResource"]
```